# ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found) in Wordpress Docker container

Tags: wordpress, docker, nginx

I have Ubuntu, nginx, docker. 
After running worpdress docker container everything worked fine. 
My wordpress site is runing by docker and has address IP:8050

After adding domain name by used **proxy_pass** in my nginx config i take ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found) in statis file (png, css, js)

This is my nginx config:

server {

```
listen 80;
listen [::]:80;
server_name domain.com;
access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

location / {
    proxy_pass http://IP:8050/;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
}

location ~ /\.ht {
    deny all;
}
location = /favicon.ico { log_not_found off; access_log off; }
    location = /robots.txt { log_not_found off; access_log off; allow all; }
    location ~* \.(css|gif|ico|jpeg|jpg|js|png)$ {
    expires max;
    log_not_found off;
}

location ~ ^/css/*(/|$) {
    access_log off;
    expires max;
}
```

}

Then I changed url in wp_option in mysql database. Redirect is worked but all statics file is not found. I take error list in my console browser
Example:

GET http://domain/wp-content/plugins/wp-smart-preloader/assets/css/wsp-front-preloader.css?ver=1.11.3 net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

When I comment **proxy_pass** in nginx config and link to the IP:8050, everything works fine.

Comment: Your config doesn't specify where the static files are.  You have to give either a root directive (for nginx to serve), or a proxy_pass/ fastcgi_pass directive for wordpress/ php to serve.

Comment: @chuex Can you show me example?

Comment: Ok, I added only location root [path to worpdress container files]

Answer (score -4):

Ok, I added only location root [path to worpdress container files]

Comment: can you explain more? cuz I have the same problem